# Why does my Android MP3 Player code not work?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, media-player, mp3

I'm trying to make a simple Android MP3 player, that will play the MP3 declared by the mediaplayer=mediaplayer.create line of code!

The XML code is for one simple button which says play!

I'd like it to play the MP3 when the button is pressed...

Can anyone help?

```
import android.R;  //This automatically generates R file (references resources)
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer; - //This allows for predefined MP3 start/stop classes      to be used
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener; 
import android.widget.Button;

public class Mp3player extends Activity {

private Button buttonPlayStop;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


private final Handler handler = new Handler();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { //Place holder for ‘OnFreeze’ parameter
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Referencing XML file
        initViews();  

}

// setOnClickListener method (buttonClick())
private void initViews() {
    buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
    buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override public void   onClick(View v) {buttonClick();}});

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music); // Sound file location


// event handler for buttonClick event
private void buttonClick(){ //When button is clicked do…
    if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str)); //
        try{
            mediaPlayer.start(); //Play MP3
        }
    }else {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        mediaPlayer.pause(); //Pause MP3
    }
}
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)`  be `buttonPlayStop.getText().equals(getString(R.string.play_str))` ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, checking the button caption whether the media player is playing is not really a good idea -- and you were doing it wrong. `String.equals()` checks for equality in Strings, while `==` checks for equality of the String reference.

```
private void buttonClick(){ //When button is clicked do…
    if( !mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
        buttonPlayStop.setText( getString(R.string.pause_str) );
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start(); // Play MP3
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            // Handle Exception
        }
    } else {
        buttonPlayStop.setText( getString(R.string.play_str ) );
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

You may also want to set your [`onCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29):

```
class PlayerActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mp ) {
    buttonPlayStop.setText( getString(R.string.play_str ) );
}
```

and in your `initViews()`:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener( this );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.GuitarPrep1;

import android.R;  //This automatically generates R file (references resources)
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer; - //This allows for predefined MP3 start/stop classes      to be used
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener; 
import android.widget.Button;

public class Mp3player extends Activity {

private Button buttonPlayStop;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


private final Handler handler = new Handler();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { //Place holder for ‘OnFreeze’ parameter
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Referencing XML file
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music); // Sound file location
        initViews();  
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        }});

}

// setOnClickListener method (buttonClick())
private void initViews() {
    buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
    buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override public void   onClick(View v) {buttonClick();}});




// event handler for buttonClick event
private void buttonClick(){ //When button is clicked do…      
    if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
             mediaPlayer.pause();
             buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
    }else if(mediaPlayer!=null){
             mediaPlayer.start();
             buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
    }


}
}
```